# Toggle button clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I can not find this.
What is the css name for UI Toggle button clicked:
I found active, hover:

```
.ui-button:focus

.ui-button:hover
```

What is for the stype code for clicked toggle button:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#check" ).button();
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for styling a `<button>` element or a Radio/Checkbox `<input>` element?

Comment: Yes it is Jquery UI check input style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before :

```
ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only
```

After :

```
ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-active
```

Based on that, i think it should be `ui-state-active`.

FireBug really help me inspect my DOM elements. :D